# Launching Ruby without the prefix "Ruby"

Tags: ruby, macos, unix, terminal

I'm on OS X (with bash) and a newbie at unix. I want to know if it's possible to amend some file such that to run a ruby program, I don't need "ruby file.rb", but instead can just run "ruby.rb".

Is there a reason NOT to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

Assuming `ruby.rb` has something like this in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'Hello world'
```

At the command line: `chmod +x ruby.rb`

This makes it executable.

Then you can execute it like this:

```
./ruby.rb
```

For more details see [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming:Ruby_Creating_Ruby_programs).

EDIT (Jörg W Mittag): Using `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` instead of `#!/usr/bin/ruby` as the shebang line is more portable, because on every Unix produced in the last 20 years, the `env` command is known to live in `/usr/bin`, whereas Ruby installations are typically all over the place. (E.g., mine lives in `/home/joerg/jruby-1.2.0/bin/ruby`.)

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned, you want to have a shebang (`#!`) line at the beginning, and change the permissions to executable.

I would recommend using `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` instead of the path to Ruby directly, since it will make your script more portable to systems that may have Ruby installed in different directories; `env` will search in your search path, and so it will find the same Ruby that you would execute if you ran `ruby` on the command line. Of course, this will have problems if `env` is in a different location, but it is much more common for `env` to be at `/usr/bin/env` than for Ruby to be at `/usr/bin/ruby` (it may be in `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, `/opt/bin/ruby`, `/opt/local/bin/ruby`, etc)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Hello!"
```

And make it executable:

```
chmod +x file.rb
```

Comment: +1 for making sure your shebang line will use whatever Ruby is in your path. When you upgrade, it sometimes puts the new version in a completely different place than the current install.

Comment: Yep, that's why I posted this; the question was already answered by several people, but I felt like it's important to mention /usr/bin/env for that reason.

Answer (score 4):

chmod +x /path/to/file

No reason not to do it, as long as you prefix the interpreter with a shebang (#!/usr/local/ruby or whatever the path is on OSX).  The shell doesn't care.

Answer (score 2):

Place the correct shebang as the first line of your file. ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

in the shell, make the file executable

```
chmod +x file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do anything more complicated with running this application, you can always create a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
ruby ruby.rb
```

If you save it to run_script, you just have to chmod +x it as mentioned previously, then execute the following command:

```
$ ./run_script
```

I doubt this will be any more useful in your particular situation than the solutions already mentioned, but it's worth noting for completeness's sake.